# DbCommand with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, dbcommand

I'm using  `DbCommand` from :  `System.ComponentModel.Component`

I'm building an object with params :

```
DbCommand command = _webERPDB.GetStoredProcCommand("mySp");
_webERPDB.AddInParameter(command, "@a", DbType.Int32, policyId);
_webERPDB.AddInParameter(command, "@b", DbType.Int32, appPolicyPrintQaCheckListId);
_webERPDB.AddInParameter(command, "@c", DbType.Int32, createdBy);
```

And now, I want to iterate it  using linq:

```
IEnumerable<DbParameter> t = from a in command.Parameters select a;
```

but it's generating following error :

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<DbParameter> t = command.Parameters.Cast<DbParameter>();
```

You have to use `Cast<T>()` because the type of `Parameters` is `DbParameterCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable` (non-generic) but not `IEnumerable<T>`. You can write

```
IEnumerable t = command.Parameters;
```